# Create Java JSONObject by JSONPath expression

Tags: java, android, json-path-expression

Using this [library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) I am trying to create a `JSON` Object by jsonpath expression. How can I do it?

Sample problem.

JsonPath expression: `$.data[*].firstname`, value = "John doe"

The JsonObject should be

```
{
 "data": [
  {
    "firstname": "John Doe"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Jayway JsonPath library offers the possibility to [set a value](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#set-a-value).